# Error in prototype syntax of javascript class

Tags: javascript, class

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(w, h) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }
}

Rectangle.prototype.area = funcion() {
    var area = this.w * this.h;
    return area;
}

class Square extends Rectangle {
   constructor(w){
       this.w=w;
       this.h=w;
   }
}
```

When I try to run this code, it gives following error:

> solution.js:10
>
> Rectangle.prototype.area=funcion() {
>
> ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in this line `Rectangle.prototype.area`. You have misspelled `function` as `funcion`. Just update it and the code will not give you the syntax error.

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(w, h) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }
}

Rectangle.prototype.area = function() {
    var area = this.w * this.h;
    return area;
}

class Square extends Rectangle {
   constructor(w){
       this.w=w;
       this.h=w;
   }
}
```